# How could I execute a C# Console app on a time schedule?

Tags: c#, automation, ado.net, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I have created a console application that reads an XML, transforms the data and exports the data again as XML. This needs to get executed on a time schedule; every hour at least during daytime. Could someone help me with this? I got recommended to use Quartz, ADO.NE or to run a .bat file with windows scheduler. Which one would be applicable to my situation?

I now open a .csproj file which consists of a Console app and a an SDK. The Console App consists of an events.cs and Program.cs file. For simplicity I only added code from the Program.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HelloWorld
{
class callHello
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
HelloConsole console = new HelloConsole();

        bool doExit = false;
        
        while (!doExit)
        {                
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine();

                switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
                {

                    case ConsoleKey.H:
                        console.printHelloWorld();

                }                    
            }

            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }

        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Windows Task Scheduler? what operating system are you working on? If this is an executable, you don't need a batch at all

Comment: I tried to use Windows Task Scheduler, but it only works on executables and this is not an executable.

Comment: You somehow made a non-executable console app? You need some kind of executable entry point... this looks like an executable...

Comment: I see that you are right. I ran the csproj file and see that it opens MyConsoleApp.exe. I searched in the folder and found the .exe file. Thank you! I will try Windows Task Scheduler again.

Comment: Visual Studio is a *development* environment. Any apps you create in it should be able to run outside of VS, in some way (depending on the specific app type).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Task Scheduler or Quartz.Net either one will allow you to schedule this to run once per hour. Quartz.Net is very powerful but it will require you to write code to handle the schedule. With Windows Task Scheduler you don't have to write the scheduling code and you don't have to use a batch file either. You can execute your process directly.

First you compile your console app and publish it to a folder. Then in Windows Task Scheduler you can set the Action to be your compiled Console App.

Keep in mind that if you run Windows Task Scheduler you will not be able to easily see the console output from your app so it might be better to have your logging write out to a file instead. You will also have to have a user setup on your machine that has access to run as a batch process and has access to log on locally.

If you are only running this specific job and you don't need to programmatically enable/disable/execute the job, Windows Task Scheduler will be easier/quicker setup.